# declaring 2d char array and passing through strings?

Tags: c++, c

Can someone explain what's happening in this line of code and how it's valid.

```
char output[][32] = {"Not present in trie", "Present in trie"};
```

Comment: That's terrible...

Comment: @deW1 This is nothing. Stealing 40 cakes, now THAT's terrible.

Comment: We are not a tutoring site. What **specifically** is unclear about this basic _definition_ you don't find in a basic textbook? And which language do yu use? C and C+ are different languages!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's declaring an array of `n` arrays of type `char[32]`, where `n` is deduced from the number of initializers in the initializer list (in this case 2).

When the variable is initialized, the contents of the provided string literals are copied into the array (string literals can be used to initialize `char` arrays in C and C++).

Comment: Are you sure about the copying?

Comment: @deW1 Yep (how else would the arrays get filled with the right contents?). Unless the variable has static storage duration, in which case the arrays can be initialized at compile-time.

Comment: @JoeKnight Yeah, if they're 32 in length, then they won't have a terminating null-character.